# Returning more than 1 variable in aggregate function

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I currently have an EMG data frame called **all_ext** that I need to extract data from. The data frame looks like this.

| LHvector | RHvector | trigger | time | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1.279411e-01 | 0.1422139707 | 1 | 0.0000 | L |
| -8.294112e-02 | 0.1112139707 | 1 | 0.0005 | L |
| -3.794112e-02 | 0.0642139707 | 1 | 0.0010 | L |
| -4.394112e-02 | 0.0422139707 | 1 | 0.0015 | L |
| 2.058879e-03 | -0.014786029 | 1 | 0.2000 | L |
| 7.605888e-02 | 0.023213971 | 2 | 0.0000 | L |

and so on (I jumped a little to elaborate).

There are 2 groups (L, R), each with 50 triggers, that has a time from 0s to 0.2s.

What I want to do is to extract all 5 values (LHvector, RHvector, trigger, time, and group) when RHvector is at its max for all groups and triggers.

What I wrote so far is `aggregatedval <- aggregate(x = all_ext$RHvector, by = list(all_ext$group, all_ext$triggers), max)` which gave me the trigger and group value and group 1 and 2, and max RHvector as my x.

| Group.1 | Group.2 | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L | 1 | 0.64821397 |
| R | 1 | 0.14332592 |
| L | 2 | 0.66621397 |
| R | 2 | 0.05932592 |
| L | 3 | 0.28721397 |
| R | 3 | 0.05832592 |

But I want the time and LHvector value when that RHvector is at max as well. I tried to do a follow-up search with

`MaxRHTime <- all_ext$time[all_ext$RHvector == aggregatedval$x]`

which resulted in an odd time value of `0.0250 0.0095 0.0310 0.0860`

I am super stuck. I feel like I can edit the aggregate function `max` to be something more useful and specific to RHvector so I can return more than 1 value as well.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Using `dplyr` : `all_ext %>% group_by(trigger, group) %>%slice(which.max(RHvector))`

Comment: @RonakShak That works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your data frame is sorted by your grouping variables and RHvector

```
all_ext=all_ext[order(all_ext$group,all_ext$trigger,all_ext$RHvector),]
```

then split by them and take the last row

```
do.call(rbind,by(all_ext,list(all_ext$group,all_ext$trigger),tail,1))
```